# Method not returning output

Tags: ruby

Why does this method not return anything when I write "puts get_rarity(n)" for any n?

```
    def get_rarity(float)
        if float.between?(1, 0.4) 
          "common"
        elsif float.between?(0.4, 0.2) 
          "uncommon"
        elsif float.between?(0.2, 0.15) 
          "rare"
        elsif float.between?(0.15, 0.14) 
          "epic"
        elsif float.between?(0.14, 0.139) 
          "legendary"   
        end     
    end
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a typo `puts get_ratity(n)`. it should be `puts get_rarity(n)`.

Write code as :

```
def get_rarity(float)
  if float.between?(0.4, 1) # see the change..(min, max)
    "common"
  elsif float.between?(0.2, 0.4) # see the change..(min, max)
    "uncommon"
  elsif float.between?(0.15, 0.2) # see the change..(min, max)
    "rare"
  elsif float.between?(0.14, 0.15) # see the change..(min, max)
    "epic"
  elsif float.between?(0.139, 0.14) # see the change..(min, max)
    "legendary"   
  end     
end
```

Read doc [`between?(min, max)`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Comparable.html#method-i-between-3F). It means the first argument to the method `#between?` should be **min**, and the second should be **max**.

Comment: just a typo in the question, not my actual code - edited

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure **float** is always in range 1..0.139?
And put smaller value first when calling `between?`.

Try this:

```
def get_rarity(float)
    if float.between?(0.4, 1) 
      "common"
    elsif float.between?(0.2, 0.4) 
      "uncommon"
    elsif float.between?(0.15, 0.2) 
      "rare"
    elsif float.between?(0.14, 0.15) 
      "epic"
    elsif float.between?(0.139, 0.14) 
      "legendary"
    else
      "undefined"   
    end     
end
```